# Android application with AsyncTask: NullPointerException?

Tags: android, rss, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask

I have to say that it was working perfectly fine before I decided to make some changes. However, the changes that I made was causing a lot of errors so I tried to undo all the changes one by one. I have tried my best to revert it back to the previous version but it still gives me the "NullPointerException" in either readRSS() or displayRSS(), which are called from the AsyncTask. It doesn't happen at all for the previous version! I've been debugging it for hours and still couldn't get a clue. Any helps will be appreciated!

My codes are as below:

```
package com.android.rss;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RSSProActivity extends ListActivity {
    ProgressDialog progDialog;
    String url ="";

    ArrayList<RSSItem> feed;
    ArrayList<String> links;
    ArrayList<String> titles;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rss);
        url = bundle.getString("add");
        startLoadRSS(url);
    }

    private void startLoadRSS(String url){
        new RSS_Load().execute(url);
    }

    //
    private void preReadRSS()
    {
    //  Toast.makeText(this, "Reading RSS, Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progDialog.setTitle("Loading RSS");
        progDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progDialog.show();
    }

        private ArrayList<String> readRSS(String url)
        {
            String title ="";
            String link ="";
            String date ="";
            titles = new ArrayList<String>();
            titles.add("KNS");
            // Initializing instance variables
            //feed = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
            try{
            URL linkUrl = new URL(url);

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                    // We will get the XML from an input stream
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(linkUrl), "UTF_8");

                    /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
                     * However, we should take in consideration that the rss feed name also is enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
                     * As we know, every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title>...."
                     * so we should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
                     * and take in consideration only "<title>" tag which is a child of "<item>"
                     *
                     * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable.
                     */
                boolean insideItem = false;

                    // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            insideItem = true;
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            if (insideItem)
                                titles.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                            if (insideItem)
                                links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                        }
                    }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        insideItem=false;
                    }
                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                return titles;
            }

         private InputStream getInputStream(URL url)
         {
            try {
                return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
         }

        private void displayRSS()
        {
            progDialog.dismiss();

          //  String str [] = (String []) headlines.toArray (new String [headlines.size()]);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    //        int num = titles.size();
    //        String n = Integer.toString(num);
        //  textView.setText(n + "items found.");

            // Data binding
            try{
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            }catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    /**    
        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(links.get(position)));
          startActivity(browserIntent);

        }

        **/
        //Asynchronous Task for downloading the RSS Feed.
        public class RSS_Load extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
              preReadRSS();
           }

           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
             readRSS(url[0]);
               return null;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
            //  progDialog.setProgress();

           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              super.onPostExecute(result);
            displayRSS();

           }

           //display progress bar here.
           public void displayProgressBar(String status){
             //todo
     }


 }
}
```

logCat file:

```
    05-25 06:07:13.406: D/dalvikvm(331): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 49K, 53% free 2550K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 43ms
05-25 06:07:13.586: D/dalvikvm(331): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 53% free 2549K/5379K, external 2563K/3200K, paused 40ms
05-25 06:07:29.416: W/dalvikvm(331): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity.readRSS(RSSProActivity.java:88)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity.access$1(RSSProActivity.java:54)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity$RSS_Load.doInBackground(RSSProActivity.java:154)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity$RSS_Load.doInBackground(RSSProActivity.java:1)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-25 06:07:29.456: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  ... 4 more
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331): Activity com.android.rss.RSSProActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40526cd0 that was originally added here
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.rss.RSSProActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40526cd0 that was originally added here
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity.preReadRSS(RSSProActivity.java:51)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity.access$0(RSSProActivity.java:44)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity$RSS_Load.onPreExecute(RSSProActivity.java:149)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity.startLoadRSS(RSSProActivity.java:40)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at com.android.rss.RSSProActivity.onCreate(RSSProActivity.java:36)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-25 06:07:31.809: E/WindowManager(331):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where is the null pointer exception? Can't see it in logs

Comment: Your logcat is showing NetworkOnMainThreadException. Are you sure it's null pointer?

Comment: Isn't there some rollback function in eclipse?

Comment: @Tim sorry, silly me, it wasn't the logcat for this app. I've just edited it so you can see the actuall error message now.

Comment: @Keyser really? Can you teach me how to do it?

Comment: @princess_blackforest Not sure, just vaguely remember using it. Try right clicking the project and selecting "restore from local history".

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're seeing, `NetworkOnMainThreadException` basically means what it says, that you're attempting to do some network activity on the main thread.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) :

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.
>
> Also see StrictMode.

I'd suggest moving the `readRss()` method into the asynctask.

Comment: The OP is calling `readRss()` from `doInBackground()` as it's supposed to be.

Comment: @James.Elsey sorry, silly me, it wasn't the logcat for this app. I've just edited it so you can see the actuall error message now. I didn't touch the AsyncTask at all so it shouldn't be the problem. It's NullPointerException.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad ya the AsyncTask is working fine, it should be either readRSS() or displayRSS() problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was mis-led by your original stack trace that mentioned the NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: @princess_blackforest does the stack trace not say what line the NPE was raised on?

Comment: @James.Elsey no worries it was my mistake, I was too panic to looking for it and got the wrong file.

Comment: @princess_blackforest put in some breakpoints, and step over every line until it breaks, that will help you work out where the problem is, THEN we can work out how to solve it